# How to properly use path parameters when binding. {Binding Path=AnyProperty[indexer]}

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, binding, .net-4.0

On the local computer, this code works:

ViewModel:

```
Public Class TestViewModel
Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

Public ReadOnly Property ReturnParam(Param As String) As String
    Get
        Return Param
    End Get
End Property

Public ReadOnly Property SimpleProperty() As String
    Get
        Return "World!!!"
    End Get
End Property

Public Sub RaisePropertyChanged(PropertyName As String)
    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName))
End Sub

Public Event PropertyChanged(sender As Object, e As PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
End Class
```

Xaml:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:TestViewModel x:Key="vm" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource vm}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Content="{Binding Path=ReturnParam[Hello]}" />
        <Label Content="{Binding Path=SimpleProperty}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Result:

[image]

On the another computer have:

[image]

I have this problem with .NET 4.0, with .NET 4.5 this code works on any computers.
What am I doing wrong?